# How to handle Datatime data with Pandas when grouping by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a question. I am dealing with a `Datetime DataFrame` in `Pandas`. I want to perform a count on a particular column and `group by` the month.

For example:

```
 df.groupby(df.index.month)["count_interest"].count()
```

Assuming that I am analyzing a Data From December 2019. I get a result like this

```
date
1      246
2      360
3      27
12     170
```

In reality, December 2019 is supposed to come first. Please what can I do because when I plot the frame grouped by month, the December 2019 is showing at the last and this is practically incorrect.

See plot below for your understanding:
[image]

Comment: You can use [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) since Index is datetime: `df.resample('M')['count_interest'].size()`

Comment: Perfekt! Makes sense

Answer (score 2):

You can try `reindex`:

```
df.groupby(df.index.month)["count_interest"].count().reindex([12,1,2,3])
```

Comment: Thanks too! Great!